# Uniquely connect an android application to a java applet on pc

Tags: java, android, applet

I want to connect my android application to an applet which is running on my pc on Google chrome on Wi-fi.. where my phone works as a wi-fi hotspot and pc as the connected device. I want the connection to work uniquely as I want commands to be passed from my application to the specific applet, on the execution of which my applet does specific tasks. Please tell me the APIs which I can look in both Java and Android or the technology I have to use to make it work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use any program, such as wamp server, to make your computer to be a localserver. It will install PHP 5, MySQL and Apache. In other hand, you will also need a little bit of knowledge in Php language to create you own web services.

Another thing you need to be aware is that to handle you connection between server and device (and by this I mean which IP you are going to use) you will have a little headache; but first things first..break your problem in little parts thus will be easier to solve them.

I recommend [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tutorial.

Comment: Ok that means I first of all have to create a server on my pc, then my applet will be able to connect to my android application on phone . Am I right?

Comment: yeah, you can do this with a localhost

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple way to connect these two softwares is using UDP. 
It is fast, it is easy to program but it is generally unreliable according to TCP. But it is already local network. I dont think that is a case you need to take care in your local wifi network.

So take a look at this tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-networking/udp-datagram-sockets.html

There are other ways like https://www.alljoyn.org/. It has more functinality but more complicated.

Comment: Why in particular do you feel UDP is a better fit?  It doesn't really seem like it would be without layering quite a bit on top, and in particular it is not clear what aspect of TCP (which already provides all that) you are hoping to avoid.

Comment: it is harder to implement. Several times I used UDP for simple communication between two devices and it makes life easier. Just prepare and send the packet and just received it. No need to have connect and listen parts.

Comment: Then you were lucky! UDP makes no promises of complete or in order delivery.  TCP adds logic to accomplish that.  So basically, you should use UDP if either you don't care, or you need to build a custom reliability layer that works differently from TCP's - something a *lot* more difficult than making the TCP calls.

Comment: You are absolutely right. If reliability and packet order are very important, TCP is the best choice. However, for simple communications, UDP generally provides enough reliability.

Answer (score 0):

You must install Server on your PC(Apache httpd or apache tomcat or other based on your interest). A server listens to request from clients. When your mobile is connected to your pc(doesn't matter wire or wireless), you can make a request to an url(say, localhost:8080/welcome) from your app.

Create an applet and connect it with your web application(in the server) using java.net.URL and java.net.URLConnection.

On performing some operation on the client, call the url of the server application and forward the response to the applet.

Comment: It is not clear that this is the best architecture, vs having the phone play the server role and the applet be the client.